# Numerical difference between Birthday and Birth Anniversary

Tags: differences

My father's DOB is 17.08.1928. Numerically what is his birthday, 89th or 90th.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between birthday and birth anniversary.

From the OED entry for birthday:

> [2. The anniversary or annual observance of the day of birth of any one...](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/19398)

Therefore one's first birthday occurs one year after one's birth, and your father's current birthday is his 89th.

This differs from the way age is counted in some cultures; for example:

> [**East Asian age reckoning** is a concept and practice that originated in China and is widely used by other cultures in East Asia. Newborns start at the age of one year, and at the New Year's Day one year is added to the person's age. In other words, the first part-year of life is counted as *one* instead of zero.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Asian_age_reckoning)

Comment: Your age is the number of full years you have lived. Occasionally, on old tombstones for example, you see the usage "in his fortieth year" meaning that the deceased was 39 (had not completed the 40th year of their life).